# Class User not found in Laravel 4 seeder

Tags: php, class, laravel-4

In my Laravel 4 app, I would like to use the User object in my Seeder class.

My seeder looks as follows:

```
use App\Models;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {

        $name = "Name";
        try 
        {   
            $user1 = new User;
            $user1->name        = $name;
            $user1->save();
            $this->command->info("Seeded user: $name.");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->command->error("Error seeding user $name: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

No matter how I rewrite the use statement, I keep getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found

I've tried:

- Use App\Models\User;
- Use \App\Models\User;
- Use Models\User;
- Use \Models\User;
- Use App\Models;
- Use \App\Models;
- Use Models;
- Use \Models;
- new \User;
- new Models\User;
- new \Models\User;
- new App\Models\User;
- new \App\Models\User;

Anyone any idea why the User class is not available in my Seeder?
The DB object is, but I need to do something with complex relations, therefor I would like to use the User class.

Comment: Have you changed the namespacing of your models recently? Anyways, run `composer dump-autoload` will ya?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange With laravel 4 normally I'd would be just `\User`. There are no default namespaces...

Comment: @lukasgeiter - thanks - I've been getting used to Laravel 5 too much :)

Comment: @TheShiftExchange No problem. I'm still totally in the L4 world (haven't had the chance to do a real project with 5 and just from tinkering you don't really get into it...)